# Hibernate returns util.Date as long

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jpa

I have domain class with date of util.Date. when i run the jpa method find the rows from db. it returns long instead of actual dates. can anyone please help?

EDIT:

Domain:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;

@Entity
public class Expense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int intTranId;

    BigDecimal fltAmt;
    Date dtDate;
    ....
    /setter getter methods
```

Repository:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ext.domain.Expense;
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT min(dtDate) as dtDate ,Max(dtDate) as dtDate FROM Expense")
    Iterable<Date> getAvlRptDates();

    @Query("SELECT monthYear FROM Expense group by Year(dtDate),Month(dtDate) order by Year(dtDate),Month(dtDate)")
    Iterable<String> getAvlRptRecords();


    Iterable<Expense> findAll();
}
```

findAll returns the value as

```
[{"intTranId":1064,"fltAmt":2.00,"dtDate":1454481056294,"monthYear":"2016-1","category":{"intCatId":5,"strCatName":"Grocery"}}]
```

Comment: Is the type in the DB a long? Is your JPA setting the date as a long? Code please

Comment: It is date in MSSQL.

Comment: Put all the code in related to your problem

Comment: Can you show a sample long value from the code. It could be the epoch date. Without the code , I cant be sure

Comment: Added the related code

Comment: Jitin is right, it's epoch date, which is a long. Here is how you convert it to Date http://www.epochconverter.com

Comment: Can anyone please explain? Why and how it is happening? I am using only the datatype util.Date. Where should I convert it to Date? in Domain getter method?

Comment: How did you get this output? It seems to be some JSON. I am pretty sure the date in the object is a `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "DatabaseColumnName")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dtDate;
```

Please use a DateTimeFormat to Map your Date of DB with your Expense Class Entity

Comment: @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) will resolve the issue basically. All others are optional.